# How to calculate date difference in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data like this:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ('1986/10/15', 'z', 'null'), 
    ('1986/10/15', 'z', 'null'),
    ('1986/10/15', 'c', 'null'),
    ('1986/10/15', 'null', 'null'),
    ('1986/10/16', 'null', '4.0')],
    ('low', 'high', 'normal'))
```

I want to calculate the date difference between `low` column and `2017-05-02` and replace `low` column with the difference. I've tried related solutions on stackoverflow but neither of them works.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to cast the column `low` to class date and then you can use `datediff()` in combination with `lit()`. Using **Spark 2.2**:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import datediff, to_date, lit

df.withColumn("test", 
              datediff(to_date(lit("2017-05-02")),
                       to_date("low","yyyy/MM/dd"))).show()
+----------+----+------+-----+
|       low|high|normal| test|
+----------+----+------+-----+
|1986/10/15|   z|  null|11157|
|1986/10/15|   z|  null|11157|
|1986/10/15|   c|  null|11157|
|1986/10/15|null|  null|11157|
|1986/10/16|null|   4.0|11156|
+----------+----+------+-----+
```

Using **< Spark 2.2**, we need to convert the the `low` column to class `timestamp` first:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import datediff, to_date, lit, unix_timestamp

df.withColumn("test", 
              datediff(to_date(lit("2017-05-02")),
                       to_date(unix_timestamp('low', "yyyy/MM/dd").cast("timestamp")))).show()
```

Comment: I have an error "TypeError: to_date() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Comment: And what if there is Nan value in `low` column?

Comment: that's because you are using Spark < 2.2

Comment: Thanks. The above is just a test data. My real data has many values  in `low` column that can't be cast into `timestamp`. How can I set these values to NaN when ` cast("timestamp") `? llike pandas: pd.to_datetime(errors = 'coerce')

Comment: then it will just default to `null`, isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yeah.They are set to null. Thanks

Comment: What about 'datetime'?

Answer (score 20):

Alternatively, how to find the number of days passed between two subsequent user's actions using pySpark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as funcs
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

window = Window.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy('action_date')

df = df.withColumn("days_passed", funcs.datediff(df.action_date, 
                                  funcs.lag(df.action_date, 1).over(window)))



+----------+-----------+-----------+
|   user_id|action_date|days_passed| 
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|623       |2015-10-21|        null|
|623       |2015-11-19|          29|
|623       |2016-01-13|          59|
|623       |2016-01-21|           8|
|623       |2016-03-24|          63|
+----------+----------+------------+
```