# How to calculate date difference in pyspark using window function?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Trying to calculate the days passed since a user first started using an application and the event the df row represents. The below code ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020818/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-pyspark)) creates a column comparing the row to the previous row, but I need it compared to the first row of the partition.

```
window = Window.partitionBy('userId').orderBy('dateTime')

df = df.withColumn("daysPassed", datediff(df.dateTime, 
                                lag(df.dateTime, 1).over(window)))
```

Tried "int(Window.unboundedPreceding)" in place of 1, which threw an error.

Example of what I'd like the daysPassed column to do:

```
 Row(userId='59', page='NextSong', datetime='2018-10-01', daysPassed=0),
 Row(userId='59', page='NextSong', datetime='2018-10-03', daysPassed=2),
 Row(userId='59', page='NextSong', datetime='2018-10-04', daysPassed=3)
```

Comment: change `lag()` to `min()`

Comment: Getting: TypeError: Column is not iterable

Comment: it might be a collision with the python's `min()`. better to use the module reference

Answer (score 2):

So, if I'm getting it right, essentially you'd want to calculate the difference of the date in the row to the minimum date (start date) of the user, and not the `lag()`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
window = Window.partitionBy('userId')

df_b = df_a.withColumn("daysPassed", func.datediff(df.dateTime, func.min(df.dateTime).over(window)))
```

This calculates the days from the first date user started an app.

Comment: Getting: TypeError: Column is not iterable

Comment: use `from pyspark.sql import functions as func` and then `... func.min(df.dateTime).over(window)))`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, now I'm running into another error. I will do some digging on my end. Error: AnalysisException: "grouping expressions sequence is empty, and '`artist`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(min(`dateTime`) AS `_w0`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap '`artist`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.