# Find difference between two date columns (eg: 5/15/21) using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two date columns(format eg: 5/12/21) and need to find difference between them in days using pyspark. I tried but getting error.Need with Withcolumn.

```
date1 -  date2  =  result(in integer format)
```

Comment: ???any leads???

Comment: What have you been doing so far ? Could you provide some piece of code ?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020818/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-pyspark

Answer (score 0):

If you have column `"date1"` and column `"date2"`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn("numDaysDiff", F.datediff(F.col("date1"), F.col("date2")))
```

Comment: Thank you. Do i need to use F.to_date for date format?

Comment: If they are, then no need. If not, then you can do `F.col("date1").cast("date")`

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate, so before I edit, maybe review this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020818/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-pyspark

Comment: its showing nan in place of 0 , how. to replace with 0?